# Project structure for class inheritance in Python

Tags: python, inheritance, convention

What is the best practice to deal with inheritance in Python in terms of organizing the project structure?

I am using something like this:

```
utils/Parser.py
utils/XMLParser.py
utils/JsonParser.py
```

Parser.py

```
class Parser():
  def parse(self):
    raise NotImplementedError("Implement me")
```

I stand for code readability as much as possible. Is there any best practice to improve readability on this by separating the abstract class from its implementations, let's say, by placing `utils/Parser.py` under `utils/generic/Parser.py`.

I am also open for better examples or better approaches.

Comment: You don't need separate files for each class in Python. Consider having them all in a single animals.py file.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Wouldn't that originate a big fuzz considering there might be numerous implementations for an animal?

Comment: Why would there be multiple implementations?

Comment: Because I can set Animal has an abstract class and multiple implementations over that class. I don't agree with packing every model into a single module. Give me a reference where that should be the right approach.

Comment: well you definitely _don't_ want to splatter your subclasses across different submodules in your package. I would probably use `utils.parsers.*`. You can still split it as separate files within the same folder, as you've done

Comment: Ok. I agree. But is there a convention that makes explicit that `Parser.py` is an abstract class?

Answer (score 3):

There are plenty of resources on Python module creation and organization. [This guide](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/structure/) includes lots of general-purpose advice and best practices.

As a very general rule, look no further than [The Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) (which you can also see by typing `import this` into the Python interpreter):

> Flat is better than nested.

So for your specific case, it seems that your initial directory structure is fine. It's clear enough, and your imports will explain the rest. Of course, if you have many generic animals and need to separate them logically, you can do that too.